# Using the ceiling function with an exponential inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If I want to calculate the highest integer $n$ which holds in this inequality

$$\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^n \geq 0.01$$

(given the result of approximately $6.64$ it is $6$) would it be correct to rewrite the equation as the following?

$$\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\lceil n \rceil} \geq 0.01$$

Comment: Yes it would, but it would help none since $\lceil n\rceil=n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Mostafa Ayaz, if $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $\lceil n \rceil = n$.

As for this specific inequality, note that
$$0.01 \leq (\frac{1}{2})^{n} \iff 2^{n} \leq 100$$
and $n \mapsto 2^n$ is increasing, but $2^6 = 64$ and $2^7 = 128$,so the highest integer is 6